# When I use content generated by an algorithm, do I legally have to cite the source(s)?

Tags: llm, gpt, image-generation, legal

Let's say that I used ChatGPT to write the text of an article and Stable Diffusion to create an image and include it in the article.

Do I have to credit ChatGPT, Stable Diffusion, and the authors of the content that helped to train their models? How should I do it?

Comment: Welcome to [GenAI.SE]! According to, ["What is on-topic on GenAI SE?"](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/), legal questions are off topic for this site. You can consider [Law.SE] instead.

Comment: What are you trying to say by "legal"? Are you afraid that a law officer reach you asking to do something after doing what you are mentioning? Are you using "legal" in a very casual and loose way, like a synonym of "right" as in "right and wrong"? In other words, are you asking about real law implications, or is this about moral obligations / social contract? In any case, you should be more specific, and legal and moral matters vary from society to society and depend on several factors.

Comment: I voted to close.  Basically, there's two main issues: (a) we don't have legal expertise here [so we declared legal questions off-topic]; and (b) there's many factors, like jurisdiction, to what extent these genAIs were used, rapidly evolving laws, and terms of service, to consider, so the question would benefit from more details.  (In practice, it's best to just cite them.)

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0 thanks, I may have found an answer here: [Can OpenAI enforce their T&Cs requiring attribution for ChatGPT generated content?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/87873). I realize now that this question mixes a legal question and a question about the Terms of Service of these generators.

Comment: Would also just add that "legally required" is NOT the same thing as "required by the codes of professional organizations you may belong to". If you are an academic or journalist, for instance, you also have to follow the stronger guidelines of plagiarism, above and beyond what is required by IP law and the T&C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L,

The short answer is, it depends. Let me explain with a few scenarios.

If your response is for a medical treatment, or for a legal treatment (so anything with a liability or regulation associated with it), I'd say the best way would be to openly say that the content is generated by AI.

If you are generating say, a short story, then ideally you do no have to.

For the last two startups that I ran, we added the following terms in our business (which hopefully) covers this point:

1. We explicitly called out that the SaaS and Website generates content (it can be anything) using AI, and where available, the platform will give links to where it understood the data from
2. Within the tool itself, on each of the responses, we added a few additional statement that gave the rights of the content generated on their account to the owner of that account.

The OpenAI terms of use has the following language, which can be found [here](https://openai.com/policies/terms-of-use).

> As between the parties and to the extent permitted by applicable law,
> you own all Input. Subject to your compliance with these Terms, OpenAI
> hereby assigns to you all its right, title and interest in and to
> Output.

I hope this helps.